# Trick for creating breadcrumb menu navigation for tutorial blog

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Recently i have made a Blog i.e Programming tutorial blog

Can you please give me a logic for creating menu navigation like this:

`Java >> Frameworks >> Struts2`

*What logic i have to use for this?  I am very confused to think, is this logic happens with SQL query?*

---

I am using : Codeigniter,php,My sql

My database structure is like this:

```
 Table: menu
---------------
 id   PK(primary key)
 menu_name     ..... 
 content      longtext
 parent_id    int(key to id)  Foreign key
```

This is an example of the data stored in the table:

```
Example
----------------
id | menu_name | content | parent_id
----------------------------------------
1  | main 1    | this is main menu 1 | 0                           <-- First level menu
2  | main 2    | this is main menu 2 | 0                           <-- First level menu  
3  | submenu 1 | this is main menu 1's first submenu's item 1 | 1  <-- Second level menu
4  | submenu 1 | this is main menu 1's first submenu's item 2 | 1  <-- Second level menu
5  | submenu 2 | this is main menu 2's first submenu's item 1 | 2  <-- Second level menu
6  | submenu 1-1 | this is submenu 1's first submenu's item 1 | 3  <-- Third level menu
7  | submenu 1-2 | this is submenu 1's first submenu's item 2 | 3  <-- Third level menu
```

Comment: are you talking about breadcrumb menus??

Comment: @KAsh Yes, you are right.

Comment: if you are fairly aware of codeigniter, you can use URI class for the same, because  codeigniter doesn't come up with breadcrumb class inbuilt.

Comment: you may go thru this forum, it will might help you
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/77637/

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do, but SQL seems like the worst possible option.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard i am trying to make breadcrumb menu for my page.  Eg. If you are currently in the `Struts2` page which is child menu of `Java` . Then my breadcrumb menu should show  `Java >> Frameworks >> Struts2`  . Please have a look to my Database structure which i have shown it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ideas is ...

CODE NOT TESTED but should get you going ....

```
public function get_crumbs($id, $crumbs=array()) {
    $query = $this->db->query("select menu_name, parent_id from mytable where id=?", array($id));
    $row = $query->row_array();
    $crumbs[] = $row['menu_name'];

    if($row['parent_id'] == 0) {
        krsort($crumbs); //sort array in descending order
        $crumbs_str = implode(' >> ', $crumbs);
        return $crumbs_str;
    } else {
        $this->get_crumbs($row['parent_id'], $crumbs);
    }
}
```

Add this function into your model class, Page_model.php

In your controlloer file include your model like;

```
$this->load->model('Page_model', 'page_model');

//Get ID

$id = $this->uri->segment(4);
$data['crumbs'] = $this->page_model->get_crumbs($id);

//Load your view
$this->load->view('content', $data);

//In your view file

echo '<p><strong>'.$crumbs.'</strong></p>';
```

Comment: Your code looks great. Can you describe it little by explaining, how we can get this model into controller and show it in my view page?

Comment: Working f9 . But your code  is not providing link in the breadcrumb result.  i.e `java >> Frameworks >> Java` how to provide link along with this result?  I think no need to use this library for this work https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Breadcrumbs-Library